# deploying django project on aws elastick beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

**Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.**

getting an error while deploying the Django project to aws server.
I have tried upgrading pip but it is not working.
also in aws documentation, any changes done in ssh terminal will get revert if it`s not in the file format.
I have tried going through a bunch of solutions given on StackOverflow and blogs.
but the solutions are bit old and aws console keep updating in short period of time. 
this error is not getting solved by.
updating pip manually in ec2-ssh.
updating .config files

here is my requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.10.5
django-allauth==0.31.0
django-simple-history==1.8.2
freeze==1.0.10
gunicorn==19.7.1
oauthlib==2.0.1
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.0.0
Pinax==0.9a2
psycopg2==2.7.1
Pygments==2.2.0
python-openid==2.2.5
requery==0.3.5.1
requests==2.13.0
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
six==1.10.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
whitenoise==3.3.0
```

adding activity.log file

```
 Retrieving logs...
 ============= i-021263909933668a2 ==============

 -------------------------------------
 /opt/python/log/supervisord.log
-------------------------------------
2017-08-24 13:15:24,774 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-08-24 13:15:24,784 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-08-24 13:15:24,784 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-08-24 13:15:24,784 INFO supervisord started with pid 2943
2017-08-24 13:15:25,786 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3034
2017-08-24 13:15:26,873 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-08-24 14:08:40,855 INFO stopped: httpd (exit status 0)
2017-08-24 14:08:41,860 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 5088
2017-08-24 14:08:42,888 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Thu Aug 24 14:01:01.892540 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3034] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Aug 24 14:01:01.892596 2017] [:warn] [pid 3034] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.10.
[Thu Aug 24 14:01:01.892602 2017] [:warn] [pid 3034] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Thu Aug 24 14:01:01.894216 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3034] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 24 14:01:01.894232 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3034] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:40.843745 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3034] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:41.889533 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 5088] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:41.900256 2017] [so:warn] [pid 5088] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:41.902693 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 5088] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:41.902737 2017] [:warn] [pid 5088] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.10.
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:41.902741 2017] [:warn] [pid 5088] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:41.904563 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5088] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:41.904575 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5088] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:44.491871 2017] [:error] [pid 5095] [client 127.0.0.1:45672] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/printachu
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:45.494047 2017] [:error] [pid 5094] [client 127.0.0.1:45674] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/printachu
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:46.496148 2017] [:error] [pid 5096] [client 127.0.0.1:45676] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/printachu
[Thu Aug 24 14:08:47.498353 2017] [:error] [pid 5097] [client 127.0.0.1:45678] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/printachu



-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [24/Aug/2017:14:08:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 198 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [24/Aug/2017:14:08:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 198 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [24/Aug/2017:14:08:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 198 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [24/Aug/2017:14:08:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 198 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/templates/poster/sucess.html  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/templates/poster/temppro.html  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/templates/poster/test.html  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/templates/poster/upload.html  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/tests.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/urls.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/urls.pyc  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/views.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/poster/views.pyc  
     creating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/
   extracting: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/__init__.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/__init__.pyc  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/settings.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/settings.pyc  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/urls.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/urls.pyc  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/wsgi.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/printachu/wsgi.pyc  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt  
[2017-08-24T14:11:11.603Z] INFO  [5253]  - [Application update app-3ba1-170824_194019@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:11:12.033Z] INFO  [5253]  - [Application update app-3ba1-170824_194019@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity execution failed, because: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
      wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
      wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 89, in parse_requirements
      for req in req_iter:
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 137, in process_line
      isolated=isolated, options=req_options, wheel_cache=wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 168, in from_line
      if (os.path.isdir(p) and
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in isdir
      st = os.stat(s)
  TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-08-24 14:11:12,027 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
      wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
      wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 89, in parse_requirements
      for req in req_iter:
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 137, in process_line
      isolated=isolated, options=req_options, wheel_cache=wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 168, in from_line
      if (os.path.isdir(p) and
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in isdir
      st = os.stat(s)
  TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-08-24 14:11:12,027 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-08-24T14:11:12.033Z] INFO  [5253]  - [Application update app-3ba1-170824_194019@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity failed.
[2017-08-24T14:11:12.033Z] INFO  [5253]  - [Application update app-3ba1-170824_194019@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2017-08-24T14:11:12.034Z] INFO  [5253]  - [Application update app-3ba1-170824_194019@4/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2017-08-24T14:11:12.034Z] INFO  [5253]  - [Application update app-3ba1-170824_194019@4] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:12:02.003Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-24T14:12:02.003Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2017-08-24T14:12:02.003Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:12:02.003Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-24T14:12:02.003Z] INFO  [5384]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-08-24 14:11:12,027 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
      wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 291, in populate_requirement_set
      wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 89, in parse_requirements
      for req in req_iter:
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 137, in process_line
      isolated=isolated, options=req_options, wheel_cache=wheel_cache
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 168, in from_line
      if (os.path.isdir(p) and
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in isdir
      st = os.stat(s)
  TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-08-24 14:11:12,027 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-08-24T14:11:12.034Z] ERROR [5253]  : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2017-08-24T14:11:12.034Z] INFO  [5253]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 541, in check_call\n    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)\nCalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2. \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.","severity":"ERROR","timestamp":1503583871},{"msg":"Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 2","severity":"SYSTEM","timestamp":1503583872}]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.798Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.799Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-021263909933668a2)..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] INFO  [5384]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-021263909933668a2)..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] INFO  [5384]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] INFO  [5384]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJKMUWT6TXOJVDPFQ\",\"signature\":\"IsOWz1TlA24RiahLe+uTqjSQQF4=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-021263909933668a2"],"data":"31ef143f-88d6-11e7-86e1-e70304c7ff2d","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"31ef143f-88d6-11e7-86e1-e70304c7ff2d"}
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] INFO  [5384]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.800Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.801Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.801Z] INFO  [5384]  : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.802Z] INFO  [5384]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Setting environment variables..
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] DEBUG [5384]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
    [2017-08-24T14:12:01.803Z] INFO  [5384]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:12:02.003Z] INFO  [5384]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:12:02.003Z] INFO  [5384]  : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
    [2017-08-24T14:12:02.004Z] INFO  [5384]  : Command processor returning results: 
    {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-021263909933668a2] Successfully finished tailing 5 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1503583922003}]}]}
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.342Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.342Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-021263909933668a2)..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] INFO  [5459]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-021263909933668a2)..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] INFO  [5459]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] INFO  [5459]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJ53OULF4R7RGWEEA\",\"signature\":\"TSczPtVwetjmhz8LHkQFvnnz\\\/j8=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-021263909933668a2"],"data":"7d79c31b-88d6-11e7-b857-955a8deeb6c6","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"7d79c31b-88d6-11e7-b857-955a8deeb6c6"}
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] INFO  [5459]  : Command processor should execute command.
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Storing current stage..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.343Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.344Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.344Z] INFO  [5459]  : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.345Z] INFO  [5459]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.345Z] INFO  [5459]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Setting environment variables..
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] DEBUG [5459]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
    [2017-08-24T14:14:08.346Z] INFO  [5459]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

attaching 01package.config file also

```
  packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []
```

03package.config

```
container_commands:
  01_addPostgreSQLPacket:
    command: 'yum install postgresql95-devel'
    leader_only: true
  02_setup_apache:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```